# Confirm reception of web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have an aps.net web application that consumes a web service. This web service is recieved by another application.

My question is it possible to have a receipt verifying that the web service has arrived at the destination (from app 1 to app 2) ??

Comment: Yes, it's called a response. If you get a response, the request has arrived and been processed.

Comment: Can you explain it for more please ? how to know if the "server 2" has revieved data perfectly or not (in case of power fail, ...)

Comment: Anyone to Help me  !!!?